# Where my home page and font options has gone?

Tags: wp-query, homepage, fonts

I accidentally deleted my home page. I have a customed theme. I hit restore page from trash yet still a different new page exists as my home page.  I searched my pages and I see a different page setting as my home page.

I have also noticed  that font options have stopped working in Wordpress even after trying to uninstall my theme. Yet I see the font changes I made just on my mobile. Is there a fix?

Edit: After changed between more themes, the font options have been restored.

Comment: It depends where the font size came from. I'd guess it was your theme's CSS, and you have an @media block that's keeping it working on mobile. Unless you deleted some CSS when you deleted your home page it shouldn't have changed the font size.

Comment: However this will be something you'll have to debug yourself in your custom theme. We're unlikely to be able to help you. It might be worth running what CSS you do have through a validator just in case there's an obvious error in there.

Comment: Thanks Rup, I have made some edits for the post.